# Как удалить элементы из одного массива те которых нету в другом?

Tags: массивы, bash, unset

```
elements=( js python3 php )

exclude=( js python3 java ruby )
```

как проверить и удалить элементы из массива **exclude** если их нет в массиве **elements**
в данном случае *java ruby*

я пробывал так но ничего не вышло

```
for element in "${exclude[@]}"; do

elements=(${elements[@]/*${element}*/}) || echo error


done
```

другими словами ели я пытаюсь удалить элемент которого нету в массиве `elements=(${elements[@]/*${element}*/})` как вывести это в консоль ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод «в лоб» с алгоритмической сложностью по операциям порядка
*O(N+M)*:

```bash
elements=( js python3 php )
exclude=( js python3 java ruby )

for ex in "${exclude[@]}"
do
    remove=1
    for el in "${elements[@]}"
    do
        if [ "$ex" = "$el" ]
        then
            remove=0
        fi
    done

    if [ "$remove" = "1" ]
    then
        exclude=( "${exclude[@]/$ex}" )
    fi
done
```

Что-то более производительное, наверное, можно сделать
с ассоциативными массивами, но старые версии *Bash* их не
поддерживают.  Так же, не удивлюсь, если новые версии поддерживают
особый синтаксис для этой операции.